# jest coverage total average threshold

Tags: node.js, git, jestjs, code-coverage, pre-commit-hook

I'm trying to uphold a minimum threshold for `jest` test coverage in order to pass a commit through the git pre-commit hooks.
I tried the following in my `package.json` jest section:

```js
"coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 80,
        "functions": 80,
        "lines": 80,
        "statements": 80
      }
    }
```

However, this will fail the commit even if just **one** of the categories doesn't reach 80% coverage.
My approach is to have the average on all of these be at least 80%, meaning, some can still be less and it would pass:

`(branches% + functions% + lines% + statements%) / 4 > 80%`

Is there a way for jest to enforce a general percentage rule, or do I have to script it?

Comment: I don't think Jest provides a way to do that directly. You probably need to analyze the coverage report yourself, retrieve all the metrics and do the average.

Answer (score 1):

After investigating, seems that it needs to be scripted.
For future reference, this is how I did it:

First of all, I added another `coverageReporters` to the jest run, `json-summary`:

```sh
jest --coverage --coverageReporters=text --coverageReporters='json-summary'
```

This would create a file called `coverage-summary.json` in the coverage folder defined in jest section of `package.json`

Then I checked with a json parser, `jq` in my case, the average coverage percentage like this:

```
jq '.total[].pct' < ./coverage/coverage-summary.json | awk '{s+=$1} END {print (s/4)}'
```

This should give the average of the 4 percentages (branches, functions, lines and statements)